# Example of restricted_package_name usage in FCM

Tags: python-3.x, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

I am currently working on two different apps but testing them on a single hardware device (as that is one of my usage scenarios) - I have seen a similar question at [StackOverflow on how to send notifications to one of two apps in the same project at firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608663/how-to-send-notifications-to-one-of-two-apps-in-the-same-project-at-firebase)

However, in my case I have two different apps (with different package names) and want to be able to differentiate when I use push_service.notify_single_device().

From the previous question I understand I can use `restricted_package_name` but after lots of googling, I am yet to find any example code. How do I use this?

Would the following usage be correct?

```
pushresult = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=requester_fcm_key,
message_title="Message Title",
message_body="Please hold on while we connect you",
restricted_package_name='com.domain.packagename',
data_message=requester_data_message)
```

It would be great if someone could share some sample/example code that I could take a look at and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looking for answers, I loosened my search to include FCM usage in other languages and sure enough, I found a PHP example at [stefanhoth's GitHub page](https://gist.github.com/stefanhoth/9935325)

```
$fields = array(
            'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
            'restricted_package_name' => 'com.example.myandroidapp',
            'collapse_key'      => 'somekey_'.$messageType,
            'data'              => array( "KEY_GCM_MESSAGE_TYPE" => $messageType,
                                          "payload" => $message ),
            );
```